# Visual Studio 2008 Team: No call stack when I throw an exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I am building the debug version of my app, with full symbols. I set a breakpoint on the following line:

throw std::range_error( "invalid utf32" );

When the breakpoint hits, my stack looks normal. I can see all my routines. But if I run, and let the exception get thrown, I see a worthless stack. it has MyApp.exe!_threadstartex() towards the bottom, a few disabled entries labeled kernel32.dll, and the line "Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing" etc.

This really sucks! Because very often I will get an exception in my debug build, and this $5000 development environment is not even showing me my own stack! I am statically linking with everything so its not a DLL problem.

Help!

Comment: Where are you catching the exception?

Comment: I am not catching the exception

Comment: Between the point where the exception is thrown and the point where the exception is caught the stack is going to be in an invalid state (because it is being unwound (so showing it is meaningless), It like asking to see the state of the stack halfway through a function call dispatch (between the call point and the entry into the function, the stack is being set up and is not in a valid state)). At the catch point you should be able to see the new state of the stack.

Comment: @TheVInn. If you are not catching the function the state of the stack is not going to be valid the program has exited. It is implementation defined weather the stack is even un-wound.

Comment: You can set the break point in the constructor of the exception. Then it will break just before the exception is thrown and you should have a stack trace.

Comment: Martin according to what you are saying, it is impossible to find out who threw the exception. That would be a serious debugging limitation. Fortunately, Visual C++ has the "first chance exception" mechanism, which I just wrote about but apparently Joel Coehoorn deleted my message (??).

Debug->Exceptions, check C++ Exceptions: Thrown should give you a breakpoint right before any exception is about to be raised.

But unfortunately for me it is not giving me any useful stack.

Comment: Is there a chance that you compiled with the flag: omit frame pointers or switched off exceptions at all?

Comment: Martin, nice idea about setting the breakpoint except for two problems. First, what if you don't know ahead of time which exception is being thrown? And second, Visual Studio doesn't respect a breakpoint in <exception>, for the class std::exception (since its part of the runtime).

Comment: @TheVinn. I could be wrong. But I believe the "first Chance Exception" mechanism stops the program after the exception has been thrown (allowing you to examine the exception). But you can stop it just before the exception by putting a break point in the exception constructor. Thus allowing you to look at the stack just before it is thrown. Alternatively you can put some text into the exception that gives you a clue about the throw point. The macros __LINE__ AND __FILE__ may help.

Comment: ovanes: Good question, but no. As I mentioned, if I set a breakpoint on a particular line when I know that it will throw, the stack is fine. Exceptions are definitely getting thrown, I get the first chance exception breakpoint, its just that the stack is no good.

Comment: That should be <underscore> <underscore> LINE <underscore> <underscore>

Comment: What is against writing your own exception class (or using e.g. boost::exception) and additionally put stack-trace as part of the exception in debug build? boost::exception for example already contains some diagnostic information, which is platform dependent. But there was a request to add stack traces. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html

Comment: I just want to be able to debug, and all that that implies. For example, see a stack trace. Visit a function in the trace. View local variables of a function in the trace. etc. These workarounds are better than nothing, of course, but why is not possible to simply debug?

Comment: If you want to debug, than put in the debugger break-points all exceptions of interest and let the debugger stop before exception is thrown, otherwise don't overcomplicate. If you need additional info for the logs, implement a consistent exception concept in the entire app. I really recommend smth. like boost::exception.

Comment: boost::exception is starting to look good. Setting a breakpoint on every line containing a throw statement is out of the question of course. It works when you have a general idea of where the exception is being thrown, but what if you are just doing regular testing and come across a std::exception thrown from the standard library? Where do you put the breakpoint?

Comment: No I mean the Visual C++ feature if you go to the menu: Debug->Exceptions a dialog will come up. Where by default marked that VC++ should break only if exception was unhandled. But you can either set for all categories the check in the Thrown column, and than VC++ will automatically break if exception is going to be thrown. You can also select there particular exceptions of interest. I think this is the point Martin offered you before.

Comment: And by the way: don't debug exceptions, but write unit tests ;) Take a look at Boost Test Framework ;)

Comment: Ohh, I see, that was you answer, regarding Debug->Exceptions. Sorry. It worked for me well. Try check only few exception and not all. If you get into the win32 API and have no source code you get such wired stack traces. Another thing: Is your app multi-threaded? Is there a chance that you get the wrong thread shown?

Comment: ovanes: Ah, I see what you mean. I don't have any "Thrown" boxed checked for Debug->Exceptions, other than C++ exceptions. Yes my app is multithreaded, and I have tried visting each of the other threads to see if there is a call stack but none of them have to do with the thread throwing the exception.

Comment: Can you assemble a sample project? I would like to take a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mix up smth. here.

If you catch the exception in some catch statement or it is propagated until main your stack was unwound and you can not expect VC++ to remember the entire stack.

For example in Java stack trace is part of the exception itself. Dependent on you compiler you can write an exception class which records the stack trace if it is constructed (but not copy constructed) and carries the information. When the class is caught you can evaluate the info. If you program using MFC take a look at AfxDumpStack.

Hope that helps,
Ovanes

P.S: This DDJ article might be helpful to you: [C++ Stack Traces](http://www.ddj.com/184405270)

Answer (score 4):

I bet the problem is that you don't have "break on exception" enabled.  I had this same problem, and couldn't believe I couldn't find useful answers to this...how did my vs2008 get configured differently?  I don't know.  But one day my call stacks just became useless when a debugged program crashed.  Finally I went and checked all those classes of exceptions to get the program to "break on exception", and now it breaks right when the exception is thrown (e.g. bad access) and I have a useful call stack to debug with.  Yay!

Comment: I got the same problem as the original poster, and none of the other answers helped, except for this one. It is under the Debug/Exceptions menu, just enable all. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you don't have any debug symbols loaded for the location the debugger stopped at. This means the rest of the call stack is nonsense.

Fortunately the solution is easy: Starting at the top of the call stack window, right-click on each greyed-out entry (e.g. KernelBase.dll!...) and select *Load Symbols From / Microsoft Symbol Servers*. After doing this for one or two entries your true call stack will be revealed.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are watching the callstack of the wrong thread.
Go to the Tread Panel, in Debug->Windows->Threads, and then select the correct thread.

Comment: I hope so.
Visual Studio will discover the callstack correctly, at least in debug-builds. But if you attach to a process after the exception has thrown, it doesn't show the right thread by default.

Comment: Are you sure you checked the callstack of every thread in your process?